# VersionOne - Assign team members to Project using VersionOne SDK

Tags: versionone

Need to assign a member to a project using API Client. I tried as bellow. but its not working ...

```
        Oid projectId = Oid.FromToken("Scope:1571", metaModel);
        Oid MemberID  = Oid.FromToken("Member:1594", metaModel);


        IAssetType scopeType = metaModel.GetAssetType("Scope");

        IAttributeDefinition atbAssignMember = scopeType.GetAttributeDefinition("Members");


        Asset newScope = services.New(scopeType, null);

        newScope.SetAttributeValue(atbAssignMember, MemberID);
```

Pease help me to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet is a working sample of how to add a Member to a project. You were setting attributes.  Since your goal is to create a multi-relation attribute, you need to **AddAttributeValue** not **SetAttributeValue**. SetAttributeValue is reserved for single/simple scalar types like text (ie Name or Date)

```
        V1APIConnector dataConnector = new V1APIConnector("YourVersionOne/rest-1.v1/",
                                                         "LLuthor", "K!@#$1234");
        V1APIConnector metaConnector = new V1APIConnector("YourVersionOne/meta.v1/");
        IMetaModel metaModel = new MetaModel(metaConnector);
        IServices services = new Services(metaModel, dataConnector);

        Oid newMemberOid = Oid.FromToken("Member:1007", metaModel);
        Oid scopeId = Oid.FromToken("Scope:1489", metaModel);

        Query query = new Query(scopeId);
        IAssetType scopeType = metaModel.GetAssetType("Scope");
        IAttributeDefinition membersAttribute = scopeType.GetAttributeDefinition("Members");
        query.Selection.Add(membersAttribute);
        QueryResult result = services.Retrieve(query);
        Asset scope = result.Assets[0];
        scope.AddAttributeValue(membersAttribute,newMemberOid);
        services.Save(scope);
```